# offsetParent() vs offsetParent

Tags: jquery

Page 141 of the jQuery cookbook notes that jQuery's offsetParent method provides a replacement for the standard JavaScript offsetParent DOM node property.

Q: How can the following be rewritten using the JavaScript offsetParent property?

```
var $foo = jQuery('#foo');
var $fooOffsetParent = $foo.offsetParent();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You <strike>have to</strike> can use vanilla Javascript methods to select the element.

```
document.getElementById("foo").offsetParent.offsetTop
document.getElementById("foo").offsetParent.offsetLeft
```

Comment: Indeed, I noticed that already and voted the answer up, but I'll leave this in place in case the questioner would like a way to access these elements and their offsets without jQuery.
EDIT: and I meant native as in without additional libraries, if there is a more accepted way to say this, please let me know.

Comment: The term I've seen is "vanilla JS."

Comment: Ah, I should've known that! :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think I will accept this answer for several reasons: it's pure js, it appears Jason worked hard on this answer revising/editing it, and he only has 25 points vs 21,300.

Comment: Thanks for the support, I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) to access the underlying DOM element from the jQuery object.

```
var $foo = jQuery('#foo'),
    foo = $foo.get(0),
    fooOffsetParent = foo.offsetParent;
```

Comment: Thanks Matt!  I will pay attention to get the next time I'm reading a jQuery book.

Comment: I use $("#foo")[0] rather than get

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you are looking for.

```
var $foo = document.getElementById('foo');
var $fooOffsetParent = foo.offsetParent;
```

This removes the need for the jQuery selector to get the element by id. If you still want to use jQuery..

```
var $foo = $('#foo');
var $fooOffsetParent = foo.get(0).offsetParent;
```